# Simulink: Controlling model from external process

Tags: process, ipc, simulink

What is the easiest way (without code generation) to control a running model's inputs from an external source (say, an external process connected via stdin or a TCP/IP socket)? Is there a generic way to set this up in a way that does not require injecting explicit TCP/IP receive blocks in the model?